# How to describe this gadget in English? ("בית מנורה עם מתג")

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, technology

How would you describe this gadget in English?

In Hebrew, I would say "בית מנורה עם מתג", that is, "a lantern house with a switch"- perhaps English has a better way to put it.

[image]

Comment: Are you after a technical description or just an everyday description?

Comment: I think both actually...

Comment: I understand that it is named "lamp base" or "lamp socket" (with a switch).

Comment: It is a switched light (bulb) socket/holder/fitting.

Comment: ... in UK a 'lamp' is usually a complete lighting device of some kind, including the bulb, for example a [table lamp](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/blidvaeder-table-lamp-off-white-ceramic-beige__1059592_pe849717_s5.jpg?f=s).

Comment: A better translation of "house" is "housing".

Comment: I would call it a "spiral fluorescent light", and perhaps add a few words describing the base/housing.

Comment: The corkscrew bulb is one style of compact fluorescent lamp (CFL). The housing is a plugin with a switch.

Comment: You may find such item in Amazon under the name of **lamp holder with switch** : https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B08RJFVRGH?th=1

Comment: Looks like some kind of “night light” to me.

Comment: @Barmar I thought there might be a common term for this entire combination. Anyway, I personally aimed at the "base+switch" (for light bulbs).

Comment: Why would there be a common term? The base is generic, you can plug any standard lightbulb into it.

Comment: @Barmar It is perfectly possible for there to be a word for the combination of base+some-bulb.  And asking for that word is on-topic here - there just isn't.

Comment: @Barmar I agree with Martin Bonner. But the word might be regional: in Chile, we call that sort of lamp an "espantacucos" -- a "bogey-man-scarer", since they are usually low-power lamps left on all night in hallways and similar places.

Comment: [Made-in-China](https://phaetonelectronic.en.made-in-china.com/product/cyJxbItHJqhA/China-E27-LED-Night-Lamp-Light-Socket-Base-Lamp-Holder-with-Switch.html) advertise it using the description 'Night Lamp Light Socket Base Lamp Holder with Switch'. Hopefully it lost something in the translation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a very specific question and is more technical than about the English language. Plus, it's unlikely to be of use to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The object in the photo is a kind of fluorescent light. It is a a narrow tube (diameter ~1/2 cm) twisted helically to fit in the same space as a incandescent bulb that fits in a lamp socket. Traditional fluorescent lights are much longer and thicker and usually linear or one circle of 8" diameter.

These 'twisted' small fluorescent bulbs are referred to as

> 'compact fluorescent bulb'

presumably because they are so much more compact than traditional fluorescent bulbs ( @Barmar).

As to the thing the bulb is screwed into (a bulb socket that plugs into an electrical socket), there is no one obvious single technical term for it. It is called by many names, which describe all the pieces. 'plug in light socket', 'light socket adapter', 'outlet to socket adapter', etc and 'with switch'.

'Plug' is the word used for electrical prongs
to be inserted into the wall for electricity.
'Socket' is the holes in the wall that you plug the prongs into or the receptacle that you screw the light bulb into.

Notably, however, the bulbs are colloquially referred to as

> 'pig tail'

bulbs because their twisted appearance resembles the tight curl of a pigs tail.

[A pigtail bulb](https://www.shawlocal.com/2017/03/30/bust-a-pigtail-bulb-dont-freak-out/agrpkbl/)

[image: a pigtail bulb]

[A pigs tail](https://fve.org/publications/feedback-fve-eaphm-on-progress-with-rearing-pigs-with-intact-tails/)

[image: a pig's tail]

Comment: I meant to ask not only about the bult but also about the "house that includes a switch" to which it is socketed.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, thank you. I only gave the colloquial version, as noted.

Comment: A socket is the thing in the wall from which you can get electricity.  A plug is the thing (usually, but not always, on the end of a cable) which you put into the socket.  Your description is exactly wrong.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Those are electric sockets (also called "outlets") and plugs. But there are also lamp sockets, the things you put bulbs into.

Comment: It was the sentence "'Plug' is the word used for electrical source in the wall, just for electricity. 'Socket' is what you screw the light bulb into." that I was objecting to.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica fixed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a right-angle adapter with switch that takes a European-style receptacle to an E27 230VAC lamp socket.

Personally, I've never seen one of these made to North American standard (flat blades to an E26 Edison base).

I can find the Euro style ones on [Chinese websites though](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S19de5c196e6a456e863fc994ecf97f7bL.jpg). They call it a "plug adapter" with some added SEO terms sprinkled in there. Also a few that appear to be made to Japanese or Taiwan standards (which are compatible with North American, but not identical).

The bulb is typically called a "CCFL" or, more redundantly, a "CCFL lamp" (Cold Cathode Fluorescent Lamp (lamp)).

Comment: I have always heard of them (British English) as CFL - Compact Fluorescent Lamp.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica They are both valid (and familiar) terms. CFL is an older technology. I don't doubt that CCFLs may be referred to as CFLs, there is little difference from the consumer point of view.